# Having Issue On Adding A Package to Dojo

Tags: dojo

Can you please take a look at this code and let me why I am not able to add a Package `dbootstrap` into the dojo toolkit?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tutorial: Hello Dojo!</title>
</head>
<body class='dbootstrap'>
    <div class="jumbotron">
   <h1 id="greeting">app</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- load Dojo -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"
            data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>
    <script>
       var dojoConfig = {
         packages: [
            {
                location: '/dbootstrap',
                name: 'dbootstrap'
            }
         ]
       };
      require([
          'dbootstrap',
          'dojo/dom',
          'dojo/dom-construct'
        ], function(dbootstrap, dom, domConstruct) {
              var greetingNode = dom.byId('greeting');
              domConstruct.place('<i> Test!</i>', greetingNode);
      });
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see in this image I already added the `dbootstrap` folder into the root directory 
[image]

but I am getting these errors:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dojoConfig` need to be declared before including `dojo.js`, so, this should work for you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var dojoConfig = {
        packages: [
            {
                location: '/dbootstrap',
                name: 'dbootstrap'
            }
        ]
     };
</script>

<!-- load Dojo -->
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"
        data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>  

<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'dbootstrap',
        'dojo/dom',
        'dojo/dom-construct'
        ], function(dbootstrap, dom, domConstruct) {
            var greetingNode = dom.byId('nodeId');
            domConstruct.place('<i> Test!</i>', greetingNode);
    });
</script>
```